# Fetch data from Mongoose without models

Tags: javascript, mongoose

Everywhere I Can read how to fetch/update data using models. I only want fetch data from the collection. I don't want any models, any schemas. How Can I easy do it?

```
const res = await this.MongoBackupConnection.connection.db.collection(this.tableName).find()
console.info(res);
```

Why this is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`collection.find()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.0/classes/collection.html#find) returns a TCursor, which isn't a fully executed query.

You can execute it with [`toArray()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.0/classes/findcursor.html#toarray), but that will fetch everything in that collection, which could be very slow.

I recommend adding a [`limit()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.0/classes/findcursor.html#limit) and executing it with `toArray`:

```
const res = await this.MongoBackupConnection.connection.db.collection(this.tableName).find().limit(20).exec()
console.info(res);
```